# How to create custom properties in a DataFormWebPart

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a custom web part that I am working on that has an XSL link property that connects it to a XSLT file that runs the web part.  I am wanting to create another Boolean field that when checked, the web part will link to another XSLT file.  I cannot use the get/set method because this is not a standard web part.  I do not have a C# page that is driving this web part.  I do have the .webpart file that has all of the values for the properties, and I think that this is where I need to put the code.  I am just unsure of how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Here is a piece of the .webpart file:

```
<webParts>
<webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
<metaData>
  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
<data>
  <properties>
    <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
    <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
    <property name="Height" type="string" />
    <property name="SampleData" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="XslLink" type="string">/home/appbar.xslt</property>
    <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
    <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
    <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string" />
    <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Xsl" type="string" null="true" />

<property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
    <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Default" type="string" />
    <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string">
                    &lt;ParameterBinding Name="ListName" Location="None" DefaultValue="MDocLinks"/&gt;
                    &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
                    &lt;ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/&gt;
                    &lt;ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/&gt;
                </property>
    <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
    <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string">TRUE</property>
    <property name="Title" type="string">MDock</property>
    <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
  </properties>
</data>
</webPart>
</webParts>
```

This is the bulk of it.  I did not want to fill up too much of the page. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .webpart is simply a definition for the web part.The backend code already exists you are simply defining what assembly/class is responsible for processing.

To accomplish what you are referring to you will need to create a new web part in visual studio that inherits from the DataFormWebPart.

From this you can then add the additional property and conditional lookup logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend this webpart through C# code and then expose the following property as a connection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xsllink.aspx

To see how you can extend it, here is the example:

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/01/26/extending-the-dataform-web-part-to-allow-custom-field-controls.aspx